# Access mongodb connection variable accessible globally in loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

How can I access the mongo db connection variable globally in loopback. Currently it is done by executing the async:

```
Alerts.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
    db.collection("dbname");
    ......................//other code
});
```

Is it possible make this db variable directly accessible from everywhere inside a model instead than calling connector.connect everywhere? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is connection pooling. Here you go!

```
    // This is a global variable to use for handing the MongoDB client
    var mongodb;

    // Connection URL
    var url = '[connectionString]';

    // Create the db connection
   Alerts.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
    mongodb = db
    ......................//other code
});
```

Here is a better explanation on [Mongodb Connection Pooling](https://www.compose.com/articles/connection-pooling-with-mongodb/)